# Javascript optimisation for a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change an image of a website with this JavaScript on GreaseMonkey (Mozilla Firefox):

```
// saves all settings of all <img> tags in the tags variable/array
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// goes through every entry in the tags array, so through every <img> tag
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
 tags[i].src = tags[i].src.replace('http://gf1.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnf0/af41c52dc08208b4463f4a4608e88c.png', 'http://gf1.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnf2/32926d2ee2884eab5015c14c73afa3.png');
}
```

The problem is that the user will see the old image before it gets changed by the script. I tried to use:

```
// @run-at document-start
```

But it is not a good idea because I can't change an image that is not even loaded yet.

I tried to optimise the code using JQuery methods but I failed. I cannot find any way to avoid the flickering produced by the image substitution. Is there something I can do?

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="smallplanet" id="planet-34020483">
<a href="http://s127-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=overview&amp;cp=34020483" title="" class="planetlink  tooltipRight js_hideTipOnMobile">
<img class="planetPic js_replace2x" src="http://gf1.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnf0/af41c52dc08208b4463f4a4608e88c.png" height="30" width="30">
<span class="planet-name  ">XXXX</span>
<span class="planet-koords  ">[X:XXX:X]</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so I reduced the script to just one line of code:

`document.getElementById('planet-34020483').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 'http://gf1.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnf2/32926d2ee2884eab5015c14c73afa3.png';`

But I am still seeing the flickering... is it impossible to change the src of the image before it gets displayed?

Comment: If GreaseMonkey supports adding CSS styles, you can set `#planet-34020483 > img { display : none }` and make it visible again after you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide and old image, change attribute and show it again. Something like this (need to test it):

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
tags[0].hide()
tags[0].attr('src', 'http://gf1.geo.gfsrv.net/cdnf2/32926d2ee2884eab5015c14c73afa3.png')
tags[0].show()
```